# Is there a way to insert input variables inside a database query using Sele

Tags: java, database, jdbc

Is it possible to put variable values from the console inside a database query using Selenium WebDriver?

For example:

```
//Get the variable from console input
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a variable: "); 
String input_variable = reader.next();
reader.close();

//Then do something like this:
String query = "select (input_variable) from database_table";`
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build a SQL query as a string, for which the linked duplicate is what you're looking for. That said, if it's possible for WebDriver to execute SQL queries against your database, your security model is completely broken.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Your link fixed my issue. You're right, my question is a duplicate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can accomplish this.

```
String query = String.format("select %s from database_table", variable);
```

or

```
String query = "select " + variable.toString() + " from database_table";
```

are just two examples off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Andrew, both of these worked! ;)